# Log shipping utility for Solaris Machine

Tags: logstash, solaris

What are the options for log shipping on a Solaris Machine? I want to send logs to a logstash server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly you will find no log shippers supporting solaris environment for logstash. You might just have to use the logstash server with lumberjack as the output of that logstash server so as it acts as a client.